# note: candidate: MyClass:MyClass(const MyClass&) error

Tags: c++

My `C++` program is occurring following error when I saving it:

```
hw.cpp|10 col 7 error| note: candidate: Category::Category(const Category&) [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|10 col 7 error| note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|14 col 9 error| note: candidate: Category::Category(std::__cxx11::string) [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|14 col 9 error| note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|36 col 9 error| no matching function for call to ‘Category::Category()’ [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|39 col 51 error| cannot call constructor ‘Category::Category’ directly [-fpermissive] [cpp/gcc]
hw.cpp|39 col 51 error| note: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::Category’ [cpp/gcc]
```

My code is:

```
class Category {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        Category(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }

        string getCategory()
        {
            return name;
        }
        void setCategory(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }
};

class Book {
    private:
        string name;
        string author;
        Category category;
    public:
        Book(string _name, string _author, string _category)
        {
           name = _name;
           author = _author;
           category = Category::Category(_category);
        }
        Category getCategory()
        {
            return category;
        }

        void setCategory(string _name)
        {
            category.setCategory(_name);
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        void setName(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }

        string getAuthor()
        {
            return author;
        }
        void setAuthor(string _author)
        {
            author = _author;
        }
};
```

What is wrong in my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: `Category::Category(_category);` -> `Category(_category);` a constructor is not a static function. It *literally* told you: `remove the redundant ‘::Category’` read your error messages.

Comment: You have to initialize the `Category` member in the `Book` constructors initializer list, not in the Body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    Book(string _name, string _author, string _category)
    {
       name = _name;
       author = _author;
       category = Category::Category(_category);
    }
```

Look at the last line. What value do you think `category` has before that line executes? How do you expect `category` to be constructed in the first place so that you can give it a new value here?

How you fix it depends on what you want to do. You can use an initializer list. You can use a default constructor.

Comment: I'm very new in `C++`, but I'm expecting `category` is null until that line, what are you mean about to use a default constructor is create a new `Category` instance before define it to `category` property, set the category name then set it to `category` property?

Comment: @Lai32290 The variable `category` is of type `Category`, which is a class. How can an instance of a class have a value of `null`? (A pointer can have a value of `null`, but `category` is not a pointer, it's a `Category`.) Since `category` is an instance of a class, it must be brought into existence by invoking one of the constructors for that class. You have no applicable constructor.

Comment: The line `category = Category::Category(_category);` creates a new instance of the class `Category` and sets the existing instance of the class `Category` (which is `category`) to the value of that new instance before destroying the new instance. That means `category` must have some value that is legal for an instance of class `Category` before that line, and you create a new class instance just to destroy it. That's probably not what you wanted. You probably wanted an initializer list to create `category` with the right value in the first place instead.

Comment: I think I understood, I can't instance `Category` IN the constructor, because before that, `C++` will looks to their properties, find the property `category` of type `Category` then will try to instance it, but I didn't pass parameter to it, so that's what it's complaining, right?